# Spring MVC - Display PDF in Separate Browser Tab & Redirect in Existing Tab

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf, tabs

My Spring MVC application receives PDF data from a distributed service.  It must then take 2 actions:  (1) display the PDF and (2) change the view to the main application page.  It should open a new browser tab to display the PDF and then change the view in the existing tab.

I've tried setting the Content-Disposition header in the HttpServletResponse object to "attachment; filename=_blank".  The PDF data are converted to a ByteArrayOutputStream and written to the response object's OutputStream, which is flushed and closed.  The controller method code is set up to return a reference to the target view following the PDF data write.  Here's a code fragment from the controller method:

```
if ((applicationData.getPdf() != null) {
  streamFileToResponse(response, applicationData.getPdf(), "_blank", true);
}

return "mainView";
```

Method streamFileToResponse() handles setting various response headers and writing the PDF data to its output stream.

This results in the PDF being downloaded.  In Chrome, at least, the user can open the download in a separate browser tab.  However, the change of view never happens -- the existing tab shows the same view that was used to launch the request for the PDF.

Is there a way to display the PDF data in a separate tab and cause the existing tab to change the view it's showing?

Comment: Can you have your client side application open the PDF link in a new tab?

Comment: I explored one approach by adding a target attribute to the form that is used to launch the request for the PDF.  This resulted in display of the PDF in a new browser tab, but also injected some undesirable side effects (there are other buttons in the form and clicking them also opened new browser tabs).  This approach also did not allow for changing the view in the existing tab.